# Type Error Read file is not defined even after importing the module

Tags: node.js, promise

The following code is written in **node version 8**

```
const fs = require('fs').promises
const [, pairA] = require('./pairs.json')

const accountASignsTx = async (secret) => {
    const fundsReleaseTx = await fs.readFile('./fundsReleaseTx.x', { encoding: 'base64'
})
```

I have imported readfile module but  getting the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'readFile' of undefined
```

2) I  taught of removing .promises  then it coudn't handle await please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you exporting not the whole `fs` module, but some `promises` as fs module. Try to change

```
const fs = require('fs').promises
```

to

```
const fs = require('fs')
```

also `fs.readFile` as asynchronous function but it does not return promise, so you can't `await` it. It have a callback parameter with will be executed when function will finish execution. So you can wrap it in Promise to wait it with `await`:

```
await new Promise(resolve=>
    fs.readFile('./fundsReleaseTx.x', { encoding: 'base64' },
resolve)
```

or you can just use `fs.readFileSync` which is blocking further code execution until it finish its work so you don't need any additional tricks to await it.

Comment: He wants the `promisified` version, and it exists, just not in that version of `nodejs`

Comment: It is not clear what he wants. The OPs code uses both approaches, so my answer is for one that is "traditional" (as for now).

Comment: thanks 

It helped me  can we do samething with .then without  using await

Answer (score 2):

I stand corrected, but AFAIK, the *`FS Promises`* API was added in *`nodejs V10.x`*:

You will have to upgrade nodejs to ***version*** *`10.x or higher`* if you want that function to work. Also note that its behind the ***`experimental`*** flag, so you will have to deal with that.

Comment: indeed, it does exist in documentation `fsPromises.readFile` and it marked as `Added in: v10.0.0`. Then maybe you should extend your answer to show the way of using it?

Comment: @SET - I don't see the need. If he upgrades nodejs, it will work as intended.

Comment: Thank you for noting the `experimental` flag part, that was what was tripping me up.